# Failed to set up deployment source for web app, using Visual Studio Team Services...Cannot find certificate with thumbprint

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have already set up a deployment from `master` branch of Git repository `mywebapp` in Visual Studio Team Services to a web app in Azure.  I did this through Azure Portal's "Deployment source" setting for the web app.  Everything works fine and I'm able to deploy my code from the repo.

I set up a second web app that is a dev version of the first one and tried setting up a deployment from `dev` branch of same repository in VSTS.  However, I get the following error:

```
Failed to set up deployment source for web app <appname>, using Visual Studio Team Services. Repository 'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find certificate with thumbprint 7477F8144DC427E94356DF03F878FD6EE7F3F83B
   at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.VsoSiteRepositoryProvider.GetCertificate(String thumbprint)
   at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.VsoSiteRepositoryProvider..ctor(String tfsImpersonate, IAdminServiceConfiguration config, String repositoryUri, String userName, String password, String stampHostName)
   at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.SiteRepositoryProviderFactory.CreateProvider(String uri, SourceControlType sourceControlType, String userName, String password, IAdminServiceConfiguration config, IDictionary`2 metadata)
   at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.WebCloudController.UpdateSiteSourceControl(String subscriptionName, String webspaceName, String name, SiteSourceControl siteSourceControl).
```

[image: Setting up deployment]

[image: Deployment fails]

I've seen posts on StackOverflow and MSDN's forums about similar issues, but those were different errors and were fixed by updates to Azure or other workarounds.  Has anyone experienced this or does anyone know a fix?

Comment: I created two Azure web apps and set their deployment source to "master" and "dev" branch of a VSTS Git repository, didn't see any issue. Is there any special step when you do this?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I set them up the same way through Azure portal.

Comment: @DivineComedian I'm getting the exact same error. Out of curiosity, which Azure Region is your Service Plan in? We're trying to set up a deployment to South Central US. --I first attempted the deployment on the 29th, as well.

Comment: If you can share the name of a test web app where you see the issue, that would help identify the specific scale unit where the issue occurs.

Comment: @moswald I'm using South Central US as well.

Comment: @DavidEbbo I just created one, and it deployed fine. :confounded: I then deployed to the broken one, just to test, and it also deployed fine. 
¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @DivineComedian you might want to try redeploying, someone in the South Central US data center may have plugged a router back in. :)

Comment: It may depend on what scale unit within the region you end up on. If you do get into that state again, please share the site name.

Comment: I just decided to use GitHub instead.  I set up a deployment for a repo there and it's working just fine.  Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @moswald +1 for shruggie

Comment: @DavidEbbo Will do. Are Service Plans locked to a single scale unit, or could this happen again if I create a new site for the current Plan?

Comment: A given App Service Plan is locked to a scale unit. You'll need to create a new Resource Group (and Plan within it), to possibly get assigned to a different one. You can ping the host name to see which one you're in (e.g. sn1-047).

Answer (score 0):

Same exact thing was happening to me, even in the same region. Turns out GitHub actions were having issues as reported on https://www.githubstatus.com. Once GitHub resolved their issues, our issues were resovled.